# How to change template file of a PageModel for Preview mode?

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I want to use wagtail as headless CMS, so I want the preview (for all pages) to load from the `base.html` file. Then I will deploy my React app on that file statically. I created the following `Page Model`

```
class BlogPage(Page):

    # Database fields

    body = RichTextField()
    date = models.DateField("Post date")
    feed_image = models.ForeignKey(
        'wagtailimages.Image',
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        related_name='+'
    )


    # Search index configuration

    search_fields = Page.search_fields + [
        index.SearchField('body'),
        index.FilterField('date'),
    ]


    # Editor panels configuration

    content_panels = Page.content_panels + [
        FieldPanel('date'),
        FieldPanel('body', classname="full"),
        InlinePanel('related_links', label="Related links"),
    ]

    promote_panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel(Page.promote_panels, "Common page configuration"),
        ImageChooserPanel('feed_image'),
    ]


    # Parent page / subpage type rules

    parent_page_types = ['home.HomePage']
    subpage_types = []
```

When I want to preview a page that I created using this model I get the following error:

```
TemplateDoesNotExist at /new-title/
home/blog_page.html
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/new-title/
Django Version: 3.2.6
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value:    
home/blog_page.html
Exception Location: My-Folder/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py, line 19, in get_template
Python Executable:  My-Folder/.venv/bin/python
Python Version: 3.7.5
Python Path:    
['My-Folder/wagtail-react-website/wagtail_website',
 '/usr/lib/python37.zip',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7',
 '/usr/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 'My-Folder/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Thu, 02 Sep 2021 10:28:26 +0000
Template-loader postmortem
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: My-Folder/wagtail-react-website/wagtail_website/wagtail_website/templates/home/blog_page.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: My-Folder/wagtail-react-website/wagtail_website/home/templates/home/blog_page.html (Source does not exist)
.
.
.
```

Is there anyway to customize how this template loader works?

Answer (score 0):

The template path for a page model defaults to `<app_name>/<model_name>.html`, but you can override this by setting its `template` attribute:

```
class BlogPage(Page):
    template = 'base.html'
```